# Como criar uma função que apague todos os espaços antes e depois da frase começar numa string

Tags: c, string

O meu objetivo nesta funcao e ter uma funcao void que altere a uma string de modo a cortar todos os espaços antes e depois da frase, por exemplo: transformar a string "     Eu fui ás compras     " na string "Eu fui ás compras". O meu resultado atual é receber exatamente a mesma string com que comecei.

```
 #include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void trimmer(char frase[]){
int i=0,a=0,p=0,b=0,posb, len;
len=strlen(frase);
    while(b=0)  {
        if(frase[len-i] = ' '){
            i=i+1;
        }else
            {
            posb= len-i;
            printf("%i", posb);
            b=1;

        }
    }

    while(p <= posb, p++){
        if(frase[i] != ' ') {
                a=1;

         }
         if(a=1){
                frase[p]= frase[i];
                i++;
                p++;

        }

    }

}

int main(){
 char frase[]="    Eu nao fui a escola!    ";
 printf("%s %lu\n",frase,strlen(frase));
 trimmer(frase);
 printf("%s %lu\n",frase,strlen(frase));
 return 0;
}
```

Comment: O que já conseguiu fazer e qual foi o resultado obtido até agora?

Comment: Tinha me esquecido, já atualizei.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bernardo um primeiro erro aparente é a comparação usando apenas um sinal de `=`. A condição `if(a=1)` retorna sempre verdadeiro, e é onde você copia o caractere, por isso o retorno é igual.

Eu fiz uma outra implementação da sua função `trimmer`. Não é a mais eficiente mas é fácil de entender:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void trimmer(char frase[]) {
    //Parametros iniciais
    int posPrimeiroChar=0;
    int posUltimoChar=strlen(frase)-1;
    int i;
    
    //Encontra primeiro caractere diferente de espaço
    while (frase[posPrimeiroChar] == ' ') posPrimeiroChar++;
    while (frase[posUltimoChar] == ' ') posUltimoChar--;
    
    //Rearranja string
    for (i = posPrimeiroChar; i <= posUltimoChar; i++) {
        frase[i-posPrimeiroChar] = frase[i];
    }

    //Finaliza a string
    frase[i-posPrimeiroChar] = '\0';
}

int main(){
 char frase[]="    Eu nao fui a escola!    ";
 printf("%s %lu\n",frase,strlen(frase));
 trimmer(frase);
 printf("%s %lu\n",frase,strlen(frase));
 return 0;
}
```

Pode testar em https://ideone.com/NAOnhc